# Seamless image replacement / update

Tags: php, ajax, json, image-processing, imagemagick

I am creating a multi-layered image editor using AJAX to send calls to a PHP script, then using a GD library to process the changes, save the new image and send the new image path back to the browser for AJAX to replace old with new.

[This example](http://www.zazzle.co.uk/cr/design/pt-card/?customize_it=true&pd=137067297785824005&qty=1&get_started_dialog=false), when you move a layer it seamlessly moves the layer without a single flicker of the image. This example uses a dll file to serve the image, I want to be able to achieve the same thing in PHP / JS.

**Idea 1**
I thought about applying a z-index to the current image and load the new image below it, once it's loaded, hide the old image.

**Idea 2**
Set the image path to a php script which outputs the raw data of the compiled image direct to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to replace the image "without a single flicker", just preload the image
(load the image to a hidden img element or a Image javascript object and then show it on an onload callback)

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty simple really.. Ta